# Handling Python Priority Queue priority conflicts

Tags: python, dictionary, priority-queue, comparator

I'm implementing a PriorityQueue in a program I'm writing. I'm ordering it based off of a timestamp, when each object needs to be executed. I'm trying to find a more efficient way of dealing with two entries having the same timestamp (same priority). 
As of now, I use a method wherein I keep a record of all the entries in a dict and check the dict everytime; however, it is possible that I could have thousands of entries in the queue and thus the dict would become large and resource intensive to search through.

I believe in other languages there's a way to dead with these kinds of issue in a priority queue.

Is there some way to tell the PriorityQueue that I don't care which order a given entry is placed if it has the same priority as another entry?

I tried finding mention of comparators in the docs, but couldn't find anything useful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry, I might not get some part of your question. But why do you even worry about this? Queues sort by the standard python sort, which will simply break the tie by previous order (effectively randomly). So you can happily have dozens of entries with the same priority, that will be sorted correctly - i.e. all higher priorities will come before, and all lower ones after.

Comment: If I try and add two entries into a priority queue in python, I will get a TypeError: Unorderable type Object() < Object(). In order to get around this, I have to change the priority value of the entry. i.e. `entry_1 = (5, "stuff"), entry_2  = (5, "other stuff")` adding both will cause an error.

Comment: Instead of putting some pieces of source code in comments, why not providing a ["Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to expose your problem.

Comment: I'm using queue.PriorityQueue. Why should I use heapq?